# How can I apply a global sized UV regardless of 3D-model?

Tags: uv

I have a 3D-model that's gone through multiple exports (unknown origin -> sketchup -> 3dsmax), and has had its geometries and meshes merged. When I apply Box Map UV via MagicUV, it differs from the standard Cube.

The cube UV is what it should look like:
[image]

Is there a way to apply Box Map UV without respecting any settings/sizes in the 3D-model?

Blender 3.1.2, MagicUV 3.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your objects are not scaled in object mode equally.

Comment: That was it, thank you. In my case the object was properly world sized, but had around 0.015 scale. To fix this I used Object mode -> Ctrl+A -> Scale to normalize it to scale(1,1,1)

Answer (score 1):

You can average islands scale:

[image]

Or you can use Object coordinates and box mapping in the image texture node:

[image]